# Attach blocks to resizing video

Tags: html, css

how do i bind a div to a video if the size of the video keeps changing? And the same question about `figcaption`, how do I move `figcaption` to the beginning of the video block

```css
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

video {
  min-width: 70%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: black;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <video>
    </video>
  <div>
    something
  </div>
  <figcaption>
    title
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I tried to calculate and set `margin-left` for `figcaption` using js , but I need a css solution

Answer (score 0):

I did it

```
body {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 70%;
    max-width: 100%;
}


video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

figcaption {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).